# Using variable in a select statement in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use a variable in select of Jquery like following:

```
 var elemName="student_"+student_id;
 $("select[name=elemName]")[0].value=1
 $("select[name=elemName]")[1].value=2
```

But this above code is not working. I want to use the variable inside above select statement. So if anyone help me to do this , I will be really grateful. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$("select[name='"+elemName+"']")[0].value=1
```

Comment: This is perfect. You are adding quotes also for string. Which is missing in others.

Answer (score 1):

Use it as

```
$("select[name="+elemName+"]")[0].value=1
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use string concatenation:

```
$("select[name=" + elemName + "]")
```